# Как запустить php7 через phpbrew?

Tags: php

Версия `php` изменяется только в терминале, на сервере по-прежнему старая.
 Установил через phpbrew `php-7.0.3`
`$phpbrew instal php-7.0.3`
`$phpbrew use php-7.0.3`
`$php -v` выдает `PHP-7.0.3`
Перезагрузил `apache`. В браузере `phpinfo()` выдает старую версию `php-5.6`

Comment: Ну видимо в апаче в конфиге написано `LoadModule php5_module  путь/до/5/версии`  вместо `LoadModule php7_module  путь/до/7/версии`  и `PHPIniDir` тоже ченить

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению с распространением ubunt и др. Ванильных дистрибутивов. Получили распространение такие кастыли как phpBrew и др. Почему gentoo лучше ubuntu потому что она идеально подходит для сервера, т.к. спокойно собрал php7 установил ввёл одну простую команду `eselect php-fpm` и т.д. и получил новую версию php пошло што то не так ввёл `eselect php-fpm` и всё нормально. так что вот так.... а для вашей задаче поставьте lxc создайте контейнер в него поставьте php7 и nginx примонтируйте папку с проэктом и настройте nginx на неё после 80 порт контейнера можно повесить на какойнибудь из портов сервера дапустим 8088 и проксировать его тем же nginx или же просто использовать его как `localhost:8088`